# How to pass a System.Action by reference?

Tags: c#, reference, delegates, action, ref

I'm passing a `System.Action` as a parameter to a method which does some lengthy operation and want to add more stuff to the invocation list **after** the `Action` has been passed:

```
class Class1
{
    private System.Action onDoneCallback;
    void StartAsyncOperation(System.Action onDoneCallback)
    {
        this.onDoneCallback = onDoneCallback;
        // do lengthy stuff

    }

    void MuchLater()
    {
         this.onDoneCallBack?.Invoke();
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public System.Action action;

    void DoStuff()
    {
        action += () => print ("a");
        new Class1().StartAsyncOperation(action);
    }

    {
        // ... much later in another place but still before StartAsyncOperation ends
        action += () => print ("b");
    }
}
```

However, only the the stuff that was added with `+=` before passing the Action as parameter is invoked. So, in this example, it will only print `"a"` but not `"b"`.

This makes me think that `System.Action` is **copied** when it's passed as parameter (like a primitive type e.g. `int` would). So, when `+=` is done later, it has no effect on the local copy of `action` inside `SomeAsyncOperation`.

I thought of passing `System.Action` with `ref`. However, I need to store it as member variable inside `Class1`, and I can't make a member variable a `ref`!

So, basically, the question is: how do you add more stuff to the invocation list of a callback after that callback has been passed and the lengthy operation is long on its way but hasn't ended yet.

**EDIT:**

Ended up replacing

```
new Class1().StartAsyncOperation(action);
```

with

```
new Class1().StartAsyncOperation(() => action?.Invoke());
```

Comment: Caveman solution: Don't pass `action`, pass `() => action()`.

Comment: Great, it worked, thanks! If you like please write it as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: Happy to. I'm delighted by this question: I never knew you could "concatenate" delegates like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A delegate type is an immutable reference type, like a string:

```
s += "\n";
```

`s` is now a reference to a different object. If you pass it to a method, the method gets a reference to this object, not to whatever object `s` may refer to next. This lambda returns, and will continue to return, whatever object `s` refers to when the lambda is called:

```
() => s;
```

The same applies with `a += () => {};`: `a` is referencing a different object afterwards, but you can create a lambda which executes the current value of `a`, whatever that may be.

Hence:

```
new Class1().StartAsyncOperation(() => action());
```

Whatever you to do `action` after that point, the lambda you passed in has a reference to the current value of `action`.

Try it at home:

```
Action a = () => Console.Write("a");

//  This would print "a" when we call b() at the end
//Action b = a;

//  This prints "a+" when we call b() at the end.
Action b = () => a();

a += () => Console.Write("+");

b();
```

Comment: This works because you are closing over the reference to `a` when you create `b`, or by relation, because you are closing over the reference to `action` when you call the operation with `() => action()`. As a result, modification to the reference is reflected later on.

Comment: Actually, after testing this in code, I found out that one may need to use not just `() => action()`, but instead `() => action?.Invoke()` - for the case if the invocation list for the action was empty.

Comment: _" what a delegate is -- other than, as we see, a value type"_ -- delegates are _not_ "value types". They are reference types. They are immutable, and so share some features with _immutable_ value types. But it is _very_ wrong to describe them as a "value type".

Comment: @PeterDuniho So a+= () =>{} replaces a? Thank you, I’ll update the answer.

Comment: Yes. Delegate types work just like strings. And like with strings, the addition/concatenation operator (i.e. `+`) returns a whole new instance. And regardless of whether the type is mutable or not, reference or value type, the `+=` operator in an expression like `x += y` is really just shorthand for `x = x + y`...the value of `x` is _always_ replaced with the result of the operator.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Low IQ day, sorry. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
class Class2
{
    public List<System.Action> callbacks = new List<System.Action>();

    void DoStuff()
    {

        callbacks.Add(() => print("a"));
        new Class1().StartAsyncOperation(() => {
            forach(var a in callbacks()
            {
                a();
            }
        });
    }

    {
        // ... much later in another place but still before StartAsyncOperation ends
        callbacks.Add(() => print ("b"));
    }
}
```

You'll get a closure over the list, so any changes will still be available when the callbacks run.